# Checks not showing in Options Menu

Tags: android, checked, android-optionsmenu

Sometimes when doing some so very simple, you miss something big.  I must be missing something huge because I am getting nowhere fast (and an hour of sifting through the web has revealed nothing).

I want to have a menu with items with checkmarks in group--just like a simple RadioGroup layout.  I get the menu, but no checkmarks of any kind.

Here's the res/menu/options_menu.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:title="item1"
        />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:title="item2"
        />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:title="item3"
            android:checked="true"
        />
    </group>

</menu>
```

And of course, here's the relevant methods in my Activity:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This is about as simple as I can make it--any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the work-around:

In your strings.xml file you can embed a unicode checkmark.  There are two to choose from.  For this project I prefer the friendlier check of \u2714.  You then swap a string with the check-mark for a string without it via onPrepareOptionsMenu() as appropriate.

Here's the xml code two strings, one with and one without checkmarks:

```
    <string name="opp_random">unchecked</string>
    <string name="opp_random_check">\u2714 checked</string>
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

I think you try to create Options Menu (it's displayed by click menu button) and according to this

> Note: Menu items in the Icon Menu (from the Options Menu) cannot
>   display a checkbox or radio button. If you choose to make items in the
>   Icon Menu checkable, you must manually indicate the checked state by
>   swapping the icon and/or text each time the state changes.

you can't add group menu in OptionsMenu. so i think you shoud use Context Menu or Submenu.
Take a look at this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: Yep, that must be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
android:checkable="true"
```

Comment: Oh yes, I definitely tried that.  Unfortunately the issue was addressed by Style.  I made a work-around that I posted below.